# Contact Microphone Noise Isolation

Tags: microphone, noise-reduction, microphone-technique, contact-mic

I have a piezo contact microphone which I am using to detect running water in a pipe. I intend to use this signal to determine the time at which water turns on or off in the pipe. However, there is noise nearby which drowns out the sound of water flowing. This noise often coincides with the water turning on or off, but is not a sufficient indicator by itself, therefore, I would like to remove the noise.

The microphone is directly attached to the pipe with flowing water. The noise originates about 20 ft away from the microphone. Though the noise source does not make direct contact with the pipe, there are enough interconnects nearby that the noise dominates the sound.

How can I modify my microphone setup - by adding dampening material or changing placement - to reduce the amount of noise picked up by the microphone?

Comment: So how does the mic get the sound from the interference - through air or through the pipe? if it's through the pipe, then you're going to have to lag the whole lot.

Comment: @Tetsujin the mic gets sound through the pipe by being in direct contact with it. How do you mean I'm going to have to lag it?

Comment: You need the interference to not reach the pipe. See a Plumbing or DIY store for heavy pipe lagging. The heavier the better. If the interference is actually part of the piping structure, then you're stuck.

Comment: @Tetsujin would I lag over the microphone, or put the microphone over the lagging?

Comment: Are you trying to record the room sound, or that from the pipe? That should inform your decision.

Comment: @Tetsujin from the pipe. I do not want the room sound.

Comment: Not sure how much clearer I can be. You need to insulate the wanted sound from the unwanted, so, get the mic as close to the wanted sound as you can & insulate it from everything else. You still, btw, haven't clarified the source of the unwanted sound & whether it's transmitted through air or through the pipe. If it's through the pipe, then as I already said, you're right out of luck.